# Youtube Analytics API: Get Earnings report for individual channel which are not part of the content owner

Tags: youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I want to get the earnings related report for the individual channels which are not the part of Content Owner. But when I am adding the earnings related metrics, I am getting 401 - Insufficient permission to access this report. When removing the earnings metrics, it is working fine. I searched a lot for this and found out that, we can not fetch the earnings for individual channels which are not part of content owner but the result I get is of 2 years old. Is there any update regarding this? Or any other method, through which I can fetch the earnings related report for individual channels?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should get a https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
scope,before accessing monetary (earnings) report.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need the client to give you an access token. From there you can get an access token and json_decode to get the refresh token which you can store in a database for offline use. Also set access type to offline.